# Rxjs doOnCompleted() not firing before a take()

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

In this bit of code:

```
Rx.Observable.range(0,8)
    .doOnCompleted(() => console.log("range complete"))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(
        item => console.log(`Item completed: ${item}`),
        error => console.log(`Error: ${error}`),
        () => console.log(`all complete`)
    );
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jacoyedesa/edit?js,console)

I get the output:

```
"Item completed: 0"
"all complete"
```

with no `range complete`

Why is this? Surely the `range()` observable will still complete? It seems strange that this doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Observable `Observable.range(0,8)` starts counting from `0`, that's why you got `"Item completed: 0"`.

Then `take(1)` operator passes only one value and sends complete signal which causes unsubscription. I think this is where it happens: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L119 and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L143

That's why `range()` never emits all its values. Also `RangeObservable` is considered as "Cold" Observable so it won't emit values until there's at least one subscriber.